# SQLite Error: near "s": syntax error

Tags: c#, sqlite

me always get this error

> near "s": syntax error

my implementation:

```
litecon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + AppAddress + "\\database\\mynew22.db;Version=3;UTF16Encoding=True";
```

error recived form this method -> liteda.Fill(dt);

```
        if (lang == "FaToMe")
            liteda.SelectCommand = new SQLiteCommand("select * from mey where trans like '%" + str + "%'", litecon);
        else
            liteda.SelectCommand = new SQLiteCommand("select * from mey where pe like '%" + str + "%'", litecon);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        liteda.Fill(dt); //liteda is SQLiteDataAdapter
```

no difference between this select commands...

```
"select * from mey where pe like '%" + str + "%'"
```

or

```
"select eng "
```

always say   near "s": syntax error

### but if using "xselect * from mey", say near "x": syntax error

i'm using this library
http://adodotnetsqlite.sourceforge.net/

Comment: You're asking for an injection attack...

Comment: what does the table mey look like?

Comment: @PinnyM no - str is my value/variable want to find that in my database, that can have any value like 'iran','usa',....

Comment: Have you tried terminating your queries with a semicolon (;)?

Comment: @brianestey - see this http://axgig.com/images/15579528865533473290.png

Comment: @PinnyM - doesn't  work!

Comment: Well you've hit one of the problems of mangling your commands like this instead of using proper parameterized queries. Doing it your way, you get caught up with the SQL statement not quite "right", as in you don't balance the comma's or the quotation marks. Using parameterized queries will let the libraries do the job for you and handle it on your behalf. Get a copy (print out) the SQL command it generates. Run it on your database manually - what do you get?

Comment: Can you trace the actual string being used (after the `str` parameter is added) and post it here?

Comment: my query work correctly in "SQLite Expert" but doesn't work when i'm trying to use that in my program...

Comment: I will try again to ask you: **please print out the SQL that your application is generating, paste it here**. Is it different to what you run manually? **Help us to help you**. What **exactly** is `str`?

Comment: @PinnyM - my final select command after added str and me received error ( str is 'pengu') - "select * from mey where pe like '%pengu%';"

Comment: Are there any other queries being attached to the `liteda` object?  Perhaps an `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand`, or `DeleteCommand`? Can you post the code pertinent to the lifecycle of this `liteda` object?

Comment: @PinnyM - all my implementation http://codepaste.net/z44hbe [access work correctly] but SQLite no ( all commands)--- sorry for my poor english

Comment: You are reusing the `liteda` object without clearing it out from previous queries.  Try creating a new SQLiteDataAdapter (a factory method would be useful here) for each query you are running.

Comment: @PinnyM - only this section have error! http://codepaste.net/g1cshj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved!

used these library and The problem was solved...
http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/download.html

thanks guys

Answer (score 6):

When `str` has a value containing an apostrophe, this query will not work because the string will be terminated too early:

```sql
select * from mey where trans like '%King Solomon's Mines%'
```

You **must** use parameters:

```
cmd = new SQLiteCommand("select * from mey where trans like @pattern", litecon);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pattern", "%" + str + "%");
```

Comment: doesn't work - and i tryed to use this command, "select * from mey where trans like '%tr%'" - but received ( near "s": syntax error )

Comment: So it's the `select` that fails; you probably have some control character in there.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is usually with apostrophe. You CAN use them but has to be doubled like, as mentioned in another answer,

`select * from mey where trans like '%King Solomon's Mines%'`
should changed to 
`select * from mey where trans like '%King Solomon''s Mines%'`.

A quick solution is to do `"select * from mey where trans like "+"'%King Solomon's Mines%'".Replace("'","''")`

That would succeed in any case.