# SQLite error when accessing first element in table using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'm having the following issue when accessing a SQLite database using LINQ.  Abreviated code looks like this:

...

```
using System.Linq
using System.Data.Linq
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping
using System.Data.SQLite
```

...

```
DataContext sqltContext= new DataContext(sqltConnection);
featureTable = sqltContext.GetTable<FeatureModel>();
count= featureTable.Count(); // count == 1
```

The following line fails with error:
"SQL logic error or missing database\r\nunknown error"

```
//currentFeature = featureTable.First();
```

But iterator works fine:

```
foreach (var feature in featureTable)
{
  currentFeature = feature;
  break;
}
```

In both cases, I'm getting the following error in debug output:

```
SQLite error (1): near ".": syntax error
```

What would cause this error?  I'm hoping someone has seen this issue before and can point me in the right direction.  But I will probably end up stepping through the System.Data.SQLite code in the debugger at some point.

EDIT: based on comment below from GeorgeT, I added `sqltContext.Log = Console.Out;`.  Based on the logging output, it appears that LINQ is generating a `SELECT TOP` command, which isn't compatible with SQLite.  The solution to this would seem to be to avoid the `First` or `FirstOrDefault` methods, or else use something like [DBLinq](http://dblinq.codeplex.com/)

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280051/sqlite-error-near-s-syntax-error.

Comment: This looks like an error in the generated SQL text. This related question's chosen answer links to an article that may help you see the text: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975554/linq-to-sql-with-sqlite-syntax-error-near-select-when-inserting?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Calling the `.First()` method generates a SQL query using the `SELECT TOP` command, which isn't compatible with SQLite.  The solution is to avoid using the `.First()` method, or to use a library which supports LINQ queries to SQLITE, such as [DbLinq](http://dblinq.codeplex.com/) or [LinqConnect](http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/).

Answer (score 2):

As tdr's answer as mentions .First() generates incorrect SQL and can't be used. I've had to convert the results to a list and then use .First() on the list as a workaround. It won't be very efficient if the results are very large though:

```
var item = featureTable.ToList().First();
```